# Features of a given scalar field

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, scalar-fields

I have to create a visualization of a scalar field given by the formular:

$$f(x,y) = x^3 - 3xy^2$$

I have to represent some features of this scalar field.

I plotted the following [scalar field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvbG5.png)but can´t really say something about its local maximum and minimum.

Every input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I plotted the [Contour lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZVgQ.png) of my scalar field but don´t really understand what they tell me about it. It seems to be a 2d view of the field from above.

Comment: "all the essential features" is incredibly vague. I have some suspicions what it may mean, but there's no way to know.

Comment: Try [contour plots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5Bx%5E3+-+3+x+y%5E2%2C+%7Bx%2C+-1%2C1%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-1%2C1%7D%5D)

Comment: @Arthur sorry for the vague description. I am trying to figure our how to interpret the scalar field in terms of local maxima and minima, as well as the contour lines.

Comment: @lhf I did it as well and plotted it in Python but don´t really know how to go from there

Comment: @Valentine can you do partial derivatives?

Comment: @Simone yes, shouldn´t be a problem to some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jacobian matrix is $O$ when $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}= 3x^2 -3y^2 =0$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=-6xy=0$.

$-6xy=0$ when $x=0$ or $y=0$, and $3x^2 -3y^2 =0$ iff $x= \pm y$, so $x=y=0$.

Thus $(0,0)$ is a critical point. The Hessian doesn't give us any further information, but if you notice:
let's restrict $f$ to some lines through the origin, $f(t,t)= -2t^3$; so for $t \gt 0$ we have $f \lt 0$; and for $t \lt 0$ we have $f \gt 0$.

Therefore $(0,0)$ is the only critical point and is also a saddle (without defining any compact set).

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you very much. Could you just explain why cou choose $-2t^3$ as an example for the restriction

Comment: @Valentine I choose to restrict the function along the $(t,t)$ line because in that locus of points the function acquires both negative and positive values. This fact shows that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Another question before I go: doesn´t  the Hessian matrix tell us that we have a local maximum in the point (0,0) - because if we write in the the Hessian form we get a matrix (3 0 0 - 3), because 3 > 0 we can det(H) = 3 * (-3)  < 0

Comment: You may have made an error in the calculation, the Hessian is a $O$ matrix at $(0,0)$. Plus at that point the function has a saddle, look at the picture you posted.